# What type should i pass in ExpressionAttributeValues for a sort key of type integer to query in dynamodb?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, documentclient

According to dynamodb [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html), we need to add type of a number as string. Refer image-[image]

but this throws an error of 'ValidationException: One or more parameter values were invalid: Condition parameter type does not match schema type' if we pass integer then it works which contradicts the documentation.
If someone could suggest to me if there is error in documentation or am I misinterpreting?

Answer (score 0):

You are misinterpreting the documentation. A number should have the "N" type. The value following this "N" is indeed a string representation of the number, e.g., "1234.5" - and that is the string that the documentation is referring to. But you still need to use "N" to say it's a number, not "S".

If you're curious why they didn't just use JSON's number type, well, the problem is that the numbers in DynamoDB have different range and precision from what JSON's number type supports.